# show: every invariant function of given evolution is constant

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $\phi (t,x_1,x_2)=(e^tx_1,e^tx_2)$ be the evolution function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that every invariant function is constant.

---

The function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called invariant if $f(\phi(t,x))=f(x)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$

My first idea was finding an invariant function. 
For example $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$ is a constant invariant function. But I don't have an idea how to proof that every invariant function is constant.

Can anyone show me the first step of the proof ?
My first thought was a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope there is some smoothness or at least continuity attached to the invariant function. Then just show that you can justify every step in
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=f(e^tx_1,e^tx_2)=\lim_{t\to -\infty}f(e^tx_1,e^tx_2)=f(0,0).
$$

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how do I justify the second equals sign ?

Comment: By assumption, $f$ is constant along these rays. The limit of a constant is the same constant.